# How can i add a module in odoo15

Tags: odoo-15

I use mac to study odoo,
And i use this document to build my first module with command

```html
./odoo-bin --addons-path=/Users/xuhongxin/src/custom,addons
```

And i successfully start the odoo,
But i can not find the estate module;
How can i solve this problem?

the document is :

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/03_newapp.html

my **manifest.py** is :

```html
{
    'name': 'estate',
    'summary': 'estate',
    'description': "estate",
    'website': 'https://www.odoo.com/page/crm',
    'depends': [
        'base_setup',
        'sales_team',
        'mail',
        'calendar',
        'resource',
        'fetchmail',
        'utm',
        'web_tour',
        'contacts',
        'digest',
        'phone_validation',
    ],
    'data': [
        'security/crm_security.xml',
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',

        'data/crm_lead_prediction_data.xml',
        'data/crm_lost_reason_data.xml',
        'data/crm_stage_data.xml',
        'data/crm_team_data.xml',
        'data/digest_data.xml',
        'data/mail_data.xml',
        'data/crm_recurring_plan_data.xml',

        'wizard/crm_lead_lost_views.xml',
        'wizard/crm_lead_to_opportunity_views.xml',
        'wizard/crm_lead_to_opportunity_mass_views.xml',
        'wizard/crm_merge_opportunities_views.xml',

        'views/assets.xml',
        'views/calendar_views.xml',
        'views/crm_recurring_plan_views.xml',
        'views/crm_menu_views.xml',
        'views/crm_lost_reason_views.xml',
        'views/crm_stage_views.xml',
        'views/crm_lead_views.xml',
        'views/digest_views.xml',
        'views/mail_activity_views.xml',
        'views/res_config_settings_views.xml',
        'views/res_partner_views.xml',
        'views/utm_campaign_views.xml',
        'report/crm_activity_report_views.xml',
        'report/crm_opportunity_report_views.xml',
        'views/crm_team_views.xml',
    ],
    'demo': [
        'data/crm_team_demo.xml',
        'data/mail_activity_demo.xml',
        'data/crm_lead_demo.xml',
    ],
    'css': ['static/src/css/crm.css'],
    'installable': True,
    'application': True,
    'auto_install': False
}
```

Comment: what is the path of estate module?

Answer (score 0):

You must pay attention to the path that odoo is having while searching for addons which is where all modules are located. You can check this via running the server in the command line and looking for the path that says is running or taking the info from, mostly is addons directory, make sure your module is running inside that exact path and if not, just add the path to the variable that stores the addons paths.